# Click through rate on the basis of search term

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I am working on eComemrce web application with DOT NET MVC. Now, I want to implement CTR as per the search term. For example if user search for Samsung, I store this search term in to DB table and it will look like:

```
Id  SearchTerm  CatID ResultCount Clicks Latency
1    Samsung     1       100        0       5ms
```

Then after if user visit any of the product from that page I want to update click for that record, like:

```
Id  SearchTerm  CatID ResultCount Clicks Latency
1    Samsung     1       100        1       5ms
```

To get this working I have used cookie to update clicks. In cookie I have used searchterm and Id of that searchterm for uniqueness of record.

Now problem is, if user open a new tab in same browser and search for another word this process goes on. But then if user again goes to first tab that is for Samsung and again visit another product or same product I am not able to update that record, as Cookie value is for second term.

Is there any other way to implement this?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can try maintaining a list of objects such as array or list in cookie variable and manipulate it accordingly with your code.